# Updating using code first in Entity Framework 5 with detached entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am developing an n-tier application with detached entities (Visual Studio 2010). I have not included the class definitions as they seem irrelevant to the logic.

The following code snippet works correctly and is embedded in a `using dbContext`.

```
dbContext.Entry(Case).State = Case.CaseID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.Entry(Case.Woman).State = Case.Woman.CaseID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.Entry(Case.Summary).State = Case.Summary.CaseID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I have added a collection `ICollection<Cause> Causes` to the Summary class.

What I want to do is:

- Check to see if a new `Cause` is the same as the most recently saved `Cause`, and, if so, change the value of a flag in the saved `Cause`
- Insert the new `Cause` into the `dbContext`

There is a flag `IsCurrent` in the `Cause` class; there will only be one record with that set to `true`; it needs to be set to `false` if the new `Cause` is different to this one.

I would welcome a code-first based way of doing this.

Comment: How do you define most recently saved `Cause` when considering multiple users of the database table? Is it the most recently saved by this user, most recently saved within the scope of this unit of work, most recently saved within the scope of this running instance of the application or service, or most recently saved from anywhere to the database?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: What is the natural key of your `Cause` class? In other words, given two or more `Causes`, which properties define whether they are the same or different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
using (...)
{
    Cause c = db.Causes.FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.IsCurrent == true);
    if (cause.Title != c.Title)
    {
        c.IsCurrent = false;
        cause.IsCurrent = true;        
    }

    //
    // other codes ...
    //
}
```

Comment: I solved this using a different approach and rather than a collection I used just the most recent record.